# Onclick event on a div with some text

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

[image]

I want to call jquery onclick event on a div which has text=OK. If user click on this div with this text, onclick event should fire.

I have added a snap for more detail info. As you can see, the div don't have any id or class to invoke onClick event based on the selector. So i need to some how fire onclick event on the div with OK text.

Comment: please add relevant code to the question. like how you make the dialog box appear

Comment: `<div onclick='functionname()'>OK</div>`

Comment: i will suggest you to put some code when you ask a question anyways! see my answer

Comment: Actually that dialogue is getting called from some minified js and css file... So no control over there, some how i need to manually hack it!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div").on("click", function () {
       if($(this).text().trim() == 'OK') { 
           alert("div clicked");
       }           
   });  
});
```

Comment: It is getting fire for each click and its not able to find div with text OK... so no alert is getting called

Comment: So try to bind `click` event with the help of parent element If you are sure that some element will be always as parent of that `<div>OK</div>`. like this `$('#parent div')`

Comment: If your popup content is coming from JS file or you are creating popup content using javascript. then above code should be executed just after opening the popup. Because while executing this script the element should be available in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div:contains(OK)").on("click",function(){
    alert("div clicked");
  });  
});
```

you need to use jquery Contains selector for this

Comment: It worked as expected but don't know what wrong there... Actually What ever the popup is coming, its coming from js file, so its not getting fire i think. By the way thanks for the JS

Comment: could you please provide any code for script so i  can check and provide any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, there are many ways to make that.

1.

```
$(document).ready(
  function() { 
    $('.dhtmlx_popup_button').find('div').click( function() { 
        alert('OK');
    });
});
```

2.

```
$(document).ready(
   function() { 
    $('.dhtmlx_popup_button').click( function() { 
        if( $(this).text().trim() == 'OK'){
            alert('OK');                      
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In Fiddle it worked as expected but don't know what wrong there... Actually What ever the popup is coming, its coming from js file, so its not getting fire i think. By the way thanks for the JS

Comment: Your popup is generated by js?